# How to remove object from a vector if it was deleted

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I'm making a console game, where the player can shoot. After the player presses the space bar, a new object is created, placed on the map, and the map contains a pointer to that object. These objects are stored in a vector. I read an article about vectors, where it says:

> Vectors are same as dynamic arrays with the ability to resize itself automatically when an element is inserted or deleted

I thought that after I delete an object, vector will automatically shrink, so i did this whenever one of the projectiles hit the wall:

```
delete entities[x + y * width];
entities[x + y * width] = nullptr;
```

But the size of the vector didn't change. Do i need to delete the object manually from the vector? I had an idea of making a boolean variable for every projectile where its state is stored (dead/alive), in order to remove it from the vector manually with the help of a loop. Is there a better way of doing that?

And also, is it safe to store projectiles in a vector? I read that vector will copy itself to another segment of the memory when it will reach the maximum size. What will happen to the pointers i have in my map after that?

Code looks something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
class Entity {
public:
    int x, y;
    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return y; }
};

class Projectile : public Entity{
public:
    Projectile(int x, int y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
};
class Map {
public:
    Entity** entities;
    int width, height;
    Map(int width, int height) {
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
    }
    void spawn(Entity* entity) {
        entities[entity->getX() + entity->getY() * width] = entity;
    }
};

int main() {
    Map map(10, 10);
    std::vector<Projectile*> projectiles;

    map.entities = new Entity* [map.width * map.height];
    int x, y;

    while (true) {
        if (_getch() == 32) {
            std::cin >> x >> y;
            projectiles.push_back(new Projectile(x, y));
            map.spawn(*projectiles.begin());
        } 

        //...
        bool hitWall = true;

        if (hitWall) {
            delete map.entities[x + y * map.width];
            map.entities[x + y * map.width] = nullptr;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is probably not safe to store raw owning pointers to projectiles in the vector. If you would store objects all you need to do is call `entities.erase(...)`. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 i addded the code.

Comment: in your code `entities` is not a vector. It would be if you had written `std::vector<Entity*> entities;` (the caveat of storing pointer applies, see comments and answers)

Comment: @spectras all entities in the game (enemies/players etc) are stored in the array `entities`, but the projectiles are in the vector: `std::vector<Projectile*> projectiles;`

Comment: Ok with the edit it makes more sense. Then it should also be clear to you that the lifetime of the pointer and the lifetime of the projectile do not necessarily coincide, so you have to explicitly deal with both (`delete` for the projectile itself and `entities.erase()` / `projectiles.erase()` for the pointers in entities and projectiles)

Comment: @kastrycznik FYI -- `Entity` lacks a virtual destructor, thus the `delete` of an Entity through a base class pointer as you're doing now is undefined behavior.  The second thing is, unless you are an advanced C++ programmer who knows everything they need to know about pointer and dynamic memory management, and have a good reason for writing such code, `Entity** entities;` is a code smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample code, I assume your vector is defined somewhat like this:

```
std::vector<YourType*> entities;
```

Therefore, your vector does not contain `YourType` objects, but `pointer to YourType`. That is, the *elements* the vector manages are the pointers, not the pointed objects.

Thus when you do this `delete entities[x + y * width];` you indeed delete the `YourType` instance, but the pointer still exists and it sill in your vector.

It might be easier to visualize if you decompose that statement to the equivalent 2 lines:

```
YourType * pointer = entities[x + y * width];
delete pointer;
```

To actually remove the pointer from the vector, you need to say so:

```
entities.erase(entities.begin() + x + y * width);
```

This would remove the pointer from the array (also shifting all things past that index). You still need to do the `delete` yourself as, again, the vector is only managing the pointer, not the `YourType`.

---

Note that unless you have a good reason, you should probably not store the pointer in the vector, but the object itsself. That would remove your confusion:

```
std::vector<YourType> entities;

// deleting a YourType:
entities.erase(entities.begin() + x + y * width);
```

No `delete` or `new` anymore, because the object is directly in the vector. So the vector manages it for you instead of just managing the pointer and letting you deal with the pointed object.

---

**Update after question edit:**

In your case, you **do** have a good reason, because you actually store a non-owning pointer. So it might make sense that `entities` and `projectiles` store pointers, so they actually point at the same objects.

So both vectors will manage their pointers, but you have to think of how the lifecycle of those two pointers (the one from entities and the one from projectiles) interact with the object itself.

Deleting the object will not get rid of the pointers, in neither of the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an iterator. Like this:

```
entities.erase(entities.begin() + x + y * width)
```

With regards to safety, for small objects that are instantiated and destroyed often you'd likely be better off storing the objects directly instead of pointers. This removes the possibility of memory leaks or dangling pointers that comes with heap allocation.